# Cannot find Struct property that exists using Go/SQLX

Tags: go, sqlx

I am gathering metadata from a file upload, and inserting into a DB table. The struct is as such:

```
// file Metadata struct
type MetaData struct {
    Owner       string
    FileRows    int64
    FileSize    string
    FileName    string
    FileUuid    string
    LastUpdated string
}
```

And here is how I am populating a reference to the struct:

```
metaDataRow := MetaData{
    Owner:       "Fake Name",
    FileRows:    (int64)(count - 1),
    FileSize:    fileSize,
    FileName:    fileName,
    FileUuid:    handle,
    LastUpdated: time.Now().Format(time.RFC822Z),
}
```

My issue is that when I try to insert this struct ref into my db, I get an error message:

> could not find name Owner in &processor.MetaData{Owner:"Fake Name", FileRows:1499, FileSize:"308.9 kB", FileName:"small-file.csv", FileUuid:"1234567890qwerty", LastUpdated:"30 Jan 20 21:13 +0000"}

Now, as we can clearly see, `Owner` exists in the struct and it has a value, as do the others. I am not sure if the query assignment failed on the first lookup and `panic`'d there, but I can't get past this to see if the others fail as well. Here is my `sqlx` `NamedExec` as there may be an issue with my Struct reference, or the binding?

```
// execute transaction
_, err = tx.NamedExec(`
    INSERT INTO file_metadata (
        owner,
        file_rows,
        file_size,
        file_name,
        file_uuid,
        last_updated
    ) VALUES (
        :Owner,
        :FileRows,
        :FileSize,
        :FileName,
        :FileUuid,
        :LastUpdated
    )
`, &metaDataRow)
```

I am hoping this is an easy fix, borderline typo.

Comment: have you tried defining the `db tab`? something like this: 
```Owner string `db:"owner"` ``` and then on the insert: `...VALUES (:owner, ....`

Comment: Oh my god I'm dumb. Thanks, that was what I was missing.

Comment: glad to help, I will post it as the answer, could you please mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `db tag` to your struct:

```
 Owner string `db:"owner"`
```

and then on the insert:

```
...VALUES (:owner, ....
```